Propagation of uncertainties when resampling a discrete signal
I have two discrete signals [(x,y) are the coordinates of each point] which have been sampled in different times. I need to have both signals sampled the same. What I thought to do is: interpolate the point of one of the signals and, using the x values of the other, compute the new y values of the first signal which, this way, is sampled the same as the second one.
On the y values of the original signals I have some uncertainties, how do I propagate them after interpolation? If you have any idea, please help me.

All interpolating techniques have undesired side effects. The DFT (discrete Fourier transform) is the easiest if the samples are taken uniformly and to reduce those unavoidable side effects in DFT the samples must be tapered (windowed) but to select the right taper/window is an art not a science, but your question is not really about physics, per se, and it will likely be closed.

There is not enough information to give a good answer. What is the span of $t_x$ and $t_y$? What are the number of samples, $N_x$, $N_y$? How uniform are the time samples? If they are random, then we need an answer that is independent (up to statistics) under $(x, y)\rightarrow (y,x)$, and we may want to pick a uniform sampling and resample both signals. When I worked in SAR, we used something called sinc-interpolation, which sound like what @hyportnex is talking about.
